# Get divs next to each other, with same height, in md, lg and xl devices and get divs in block in smaller devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using bootstrap and I want that in medium, large and extra large devices get the first layout of the image below, where there is a image at the left and then some information at right. And these 2 areas (the image and the informations div) occupy the full .container div width and have always the same height.

Then in smaller devices I want to get the layout in the image below, where the image is above and the informations below.

Image to demonstrate the layout that Im trying to get:

**Image:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7goYA.png)

But Im getting this: https://jsfiddle.net/ce228caL/

Do you know how to properly get the layouts of the image?

**html:**

```
<div class="container py-md-5">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-auto">
      <img style="width: 100%; height: auto" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x400"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-lg-2 d-md-flex">
      <div class="d-none d-md-block details-title d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
        <span class="font-size-sm font-weight-semi-bold">Title</span>
        <h1 class="h5 mb-0 title">Subtitle</h1>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-block link">Link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**css**

```
.title{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid $light-gray;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;

}

.subtitle{
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.link{
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified your first div to have all 12 columns on every screen size

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-auto">
```

Reduce it to 10 on medium and up, so the 2nd 2-column div will fit in the row. also set the 2nd div to `col-md-2`, so it occupies 2 columns on medium. Also, I am not sure why you would want to solve this using flexbox instead of the classic [grid](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)

```
<div class="container py-md-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-12">
      <img style="width: 100%; height: auto" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x400"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-2 col-12">
      <div class="d-none d-md-block details-title d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
        <span class="font-size-sm font-weight-semi-bold">Title</span>
        <h1 class="h5 mb-0 title">Subtitle</h1>
        <span class="subtitle font-size-sm font-weight-semi-bold">Subtitle 2</span>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-block link">Link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but its not working properly, in large devices its ok but then in medium devices the layout should be the same of larger devices the only difference is that because there is less space the image should occupy less space and the right div with informations should also occupy less space.  And then in small devices the above and below divs are not occupying the same width, the above div with the image has much more width, the div below with the informations is ok aligned at center, but the above div with the image is occupying much more width, is not also aligned at center.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread. I changed my answer and it should now work for medium.

Comment: Made another edit and added `col-12` as the default behaviour (for everything below medium) to the columns.

Comment: Thanks again! But like that the div with the details dont have the same height of the image: https://jsfiddle.net/6uc3w5zz/. Do you know why?